# Set Liferay Hook on session timeout

Tags: java, session, liferay, session-timeout

I want to write a Hook in Java that is executed if the session of my Liferay 5.2.3 Portal times out.

I managed to write a Hook that is executed whenever the user clicks the logout link with the following setup in the `liferay-hook.xml`:

```
<hook>
    <event>
        <event-class>com.extensions.hooks.LogoutHook</event-class>
        <event-type>logout.events.pre</event-type>
    </event>
</hook>
```

However the Logout Hook does not get called if the session times out, but I need to execute the same method on a timeout. I did not find an event-type for a session timeout.

Is there a way to execute a Java-Method when the session times out and identify the User-ID of the ended session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an event which will be triggered upon **Session Expiry/TimeOut** event of User Session,

```
# Servlet session destroy event
servlet.session.destroy.events = com.extensions.hooks.CustomPreSessionExpireAction
```

You can either add this property in `liferay-hook.xml` or `portal.properties` [Written in Hook] or `portal-ext.properties`.

And can be used as ,

```
public class CustomPreSessionExpireAction extends SessionAction {

    @Override
    public void run(HttpSession session) throws ActionException {
        //Code
    }
}
```

However, We can only use `HttpSession` here. So, you need to figure out the way to get `userId` here.

Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot, this is working! I can get the user-ID from a session attribute `Long id = (Long) session.getAttribute("USER_ID");`

Comment: will it be called even if the browser closed before session expired?

Comment: No, it will be invoked only when the server session for the user has expired.

Comment: Thankss a lot, it worked (``CustomPreSessionExpireAction``) even  browser is closed. But, I have set ``session.timeout=1`` (1 minute) it works fine as expected. But ``CustomPreSessionExpireAction`` being called after 10 to 20 seconds (after expected session out time). why is that?