# How to check if Liferay session has timed out in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-aui

We're using Liferay for management of portlets and session, and rest of the application is built using angular. The portlets within themselves are single page applications. The problem that we're facing is that liferay doesn't redirect the user when session times out and an ajax request is performed. If the user navigates to some other portlet or reloads the page, liferay does identify that session has timed out, but if the user clicks on some link on the page, which doesn't result in page reload, liferay doesn't identify that session has timed out.

To fix this issue, I am trying to identify using Javascript code, if the liferay session is valid or not. I am able to access Liferay.Session Object in my JS, but am not sure what function or field I can use to identify if session is valid or not.

Can someone help me with this?

Below is the code using which we're getting access to the Lieray session.

```
AUI().use('liferay-session', function(A) {
  //Liferay.Session
  //some logic
}
```

We're using Liferay 6.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to `Liferay.Session` object you should be able to do this to get the state of the session:

```
Liferay.Session.get('sessionState');
```

It will return "active" if the session is still active.

Comment: Even if my session is timed out or I am logged out of liferay and on login page, still I am getting this value as true. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Consider you can setup the portal to automatic autoextend session time. The session will never expired.

Setup a portal-ext.properties file with this custom value

```
session.timeout.warning=0
session.timeout.auto.extend=true
```

It could be a real scenario for your app?

Answer (score 0):

You can poll through AJAX call and retrieve the status of the session from Java Code or create a hidden field with the time that remains in each page load. 
Then in Javascript do a substraction from current time and in the case that the user is out-of-time you can perform any action that you want.

Is a sticky approach but could be useful for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a hook which will get triggered on session timeout.

As mention here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302153/2834053

Hope this helps.